# List containing nullable values to a nullable List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a `List<T?>` containing null values (which, I suppose, is not forbidden). If one element of this list is null, I want the entire list to be null (what Haskell people call `sequence`). The following pseudocode demonstrates what I want to do:

```
fun <T> sequence(a : List<T?>) : List<T>? {
    return 
        a.fold(
            listOf(),
            { 
                prevArray, element -> 
                    if(element == null) null else prevArray + element 
            })
}
```

This is pseudocode because the compiler complains that `Null can not be a value of a non-null type kotlin.collections.List<T>`.

What's the idiomatic way to express what I want to in Kotlin? Using Java's `Optional` type, this is at least compilable:

```
fun <T> sequence(a : List<T?>) : Optional<List<T>> {
    return 
        a.fold(
            Optional.of(listOf()),
            { 
                prevArray, element -> 
                    if(element == null) Optional.empty<List<T>>() else Optional.of(prevArray + element) 
            })
}
```

But Kotlin has many operators and functionalities regarding null handling, so I thought using null directly would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a [non-local return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) to return from the `sequence` function:

```
fun <T> sequence(a: List<T?>): List<T>? {
    return a.fold(listOf()) {
        prevArray, element ->
        if (element == null) return null else prevArray + element
    }
}
```

However, I would solve the problem you described with a simple `if`-expression, to prevent lots of list allocations which happen because the list addition creates a new list backed by array for each element. The unchecked cast warning is suppressed below because the compiler cannot figure out that the list does not contain nulls at that point, although we can clearly see that is the case:

```
fun <T> sequence(a: List<T?>): List<T>? {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return if (a.any { it == null }) null else a as List<T>
}
```

Comment: Note that to use the second variant, you must be sure that the list `a` won't have new `null` elements added later.

Comment: Or you can just copy it one time to avoid the problem @ilya mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Using [Konad](https://github.com/lucapiccinelli/konad#flatten) library you can now do the following:

```
fun <T> sequence(a : List<T?>) : List<T>? = a.flatten()?.toList()
```